How to use the ptype argument in unnest_longer()
I have a data.frame that looks like this.
library(tidyverse)

# Create a data frame with a list-column
df <-
  tibble(
    id = c(1,2),
    lst = list(c(1,2), c('a', 'b'))
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id lst      
#>   <dbl> <list>   
#> 1     1 <dbl [2]>
#> 2     2 <chr [2]>

I would like to unnest lst to a character column using the unnest_longer() function.  However, when I supply the ptype argument, I still get an error.  How can I do this?
# try to unnest
unnest_longer(df, lst, ptype = 'character')
#> Error in `col_to_long()`:
#> ! Can't combine `..1$lst` <double> and `..3$lst` <character>.
#> Backtrace:
#>      x
#>   1. +-tidyr::unnest_longer(df, lst, ptype = "character")
#>   2. | \-tidyr:::col_to_long(...)
#>   3. |   \-vctrs::vec_ptype_common(ptype, !!!col)
#>   4. \-vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
#>   5.   \-vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
#>   6.     +-base::withRestarts(...)
#>   7.     | \-base (local) withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
#>   8.     |   \-base (local) doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
#>   9.     \-vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
#>  10.       \-vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
#>  11.         \-vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
#>  12.           \-rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = call)

Created on 2024-06-04 with reprex v2.0.2

If you look at the code for unnest_longer, the ptype argument is not used until after the call to col_to_long - which is where the error is generated. So I suspect the way round this is to convert to character before the unnest, rather than try to use ptype (i.e. df %>% mutate(lst = map(lst, as.character)) %>% unnest_longer(lst))

unnest_longer uses unchop (which uses ptype internally) and one of the examples at the bottom of the ?unchop help file has a comment that says:  unchop will error if the types are not compatible so it seems that ptype does not do conversions.

col_to_long() calls vec_ptype_common() from the vctrs package. The vctrs package has different rules about coercion than base R (as you found out). For example, c(factor("a"), "b") versus vctrs::vec_c(factor("a"), "b"). Another difference is that numeric can be coerced to character in base R c(1, "b"), but cannot be cast in vctrs vctrs::vec_c(1:3, c('a', 'b', 'c')). As others have mentioned this forces you to make the coercion before unnest_longer().

It seems the elements need to be one type already to be treated with ptype or transform. As a workaround use purrr::map and as.character to cast each element before unnesting.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(lst = purrr::map(lst, ~ as.character(.x))) %>% 
  unnest_longer(lst)
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     id lst  
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 1    
2     1 2    
3     2 a    
4     2 b

